# CSS is blocked while display none

Tags: html, css

I am creating a tabs using simple css and JS. Basically the element has "Display:block" and after clicking a button it has "Display:block". But for some reason, I guess because of "display:none" CSS is not applied to the element I have.

I am using a Frappe library to put Gantt Chart to website, but Frappe's CSS is not working after I enable it by clicking the button into the menu. I tried different approaches but still does not work. I have no clue how to fix that, so any advice would be appreciated.

So I am not sure how to fix that so my tabs will work.

```js
function clickHandle(evt, animalName) {
  let i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // This is to clear the previous clicked content.
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Set the tab to be "active".
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Display the clicked tab and set it to active.
  document.getElementById(animalName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="clickHandle(event, 'Cat')">Cat</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="clickHandle(event, 'Bear')">Bear</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="clickHandle(event, 'Dog')">Dog</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Cat" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Meowww.</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="Bear" class="tabcontent">
    <   <div class="container" style="width: 80%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <script src="dist/frappe-gantt.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/frappe-gantt.css">
  <div class="container">
        <h2>Gantt Chart</h2>
        <div class="gantt-target"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="testjs.js"></script>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
  </div>

  <div id="Dog" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Bork Bork.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose I don't understand the question .. The code as it stands works .. The tabs function properly ...  What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Tabs are working fine, thats true, the problem is that CSS is not getting applied when I am turning a tab with gantt-chart